# Using CMD commands with an executable python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, executable, pyinstaller

After writing the script below(which works perfectly), I open the `cmd.exe` windows prompt and type the following

```
pyinstaller -F --windowed myscript.py
```

which gives me a file called "myscript.exe".

The problem is when I open the executable and press the button, nothing happens. I think there is a problem with this line:

```
check_output("shutdown -s -t 60", shell=True)
```

Even though the script works "as a script", it doesn't work as an executable.
I've tried other syntax like

```
os.system("shutdown -s -t 60")
```

but they don't seem to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import check_output,CalledProcessError

class main_gui:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        master.geometry("250x100")
        self.button1=Button(self.master,
                            text="Press me",
                            font="Times 10 bold",
                            command=self.shutdown)
        self.button1.pack()

    def shutdown(self):
        try:
            check_output("shutdown -s -t 60", shell=True)
            print("Computer will shutdown in 60 seconds")
        except CalledProcessError:
            print("Already pressed")

root = Tk()
my_gui = main_gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you can do:**

using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-f", "-s", "-t", "60"])
```

this will work. with `--windowed`

It seems thats there is a problem with `check_output` with `--windowed` flag :/

> **Edit1:**

based on [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) comments. *Also was my research results was but now it seems proof.*

Use `check_call` and a creation flag to avoid creating a console window. For example: `CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000; check_call('shutdown -s -t 60', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)`.

Regarding `check_output`, since it overrides `stdout`, `Popen` has to also duplicate inheritable copies of the existing stdin and stderr handles. This will fail if they're invalid. When run from a console in Windows 7, a GUI can inherit invalid standard handles. A workaround is to override all 3 handles. For example: `output = check_output('shutdown -s -t 60', stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW`

> **Edit2:**

You can also add a icon directly with pyinstaller...
Reference: [Windows and Mac OS X specific options](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options)

Comment: Use `check_call` and a creation flag to avoid creating a console window. For example:  `CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;` `check_call('shutdown -s -t 60', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)`.

Comment: Regarding `check_output`, since it overrides `stdout`, `Popen` has to also duplicate inheritable copies of the existing stdin and stderr handles. This will fail if they're invalid. When run from a console in Windows 7, a GUI can inherit invalid standard handles. A workaround is to override all 3 handles. For example: `output = check_output('shutdown -s -t 60', stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`, `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)`.

Comment: Using the above method worked on the mentioned script but when I tried it with a longer one, the button somehow opened another instance of the application.

Comment: EDIT: Sometimes it works (the longer script), sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the button opens another instance of the program without executing the command. I created two executables and then put them in the same directory, none of them works, when I deleted one of them, the other magically started working.

Comment: EDIT2: I created another executable and made a copy of it, I changed the copy's icon using "ResHacker". None of them works when in the same folder. Deleting the original somehow makes the copy (with the custom icon) work normally. Can someone explain this ?

Comment: @SinaUser, we don't have enough information. Use `logging` to write errors to a file, instead of depending on printing information to stdout and exceptions to stderr. They aren't available by default in a GUI process.

Comment: I think I've found the problem, my script has the same file name of a method used in the same script. When I press the button, the file itself is called again instead of the method (as they have the same name). When I tried changing the script name, no errors have been encountered.